# Sorting a VB.net List by a class value

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

I have a list (i.e. `Dim nList as new List(of className)`).  Each class has a property named `zIndex` (i.e. `className.zIndex`).  Is it possible to sort the elements of the list by the zIndex variable in all of the elements of the list?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming you have LINQ at your disposal:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim list = New List(Of Person)()
    'Pretend the list has stuff in it
    Dim sorted = list.OrderBy(Function(x) x.zIndex)
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public Property zIndex As Integer
End Class
```

Or if LINQ isn't your thing:

```
Dim list = New List(Of Person)()
list.Sort(Function(x, y) x.zIndex.CompareTo(y.zIndex))
'Will sort list in place
```

LINQ offers more flexibility; such as being able to use `ThenBy` if you want to order by more than one thing. It also makes for a slightly cleaner syntax.

Comment: I was unable to use the LINQ example, how would I enable that?  I got the second one to work though, thanks :)

Comment: @DalexL It depends on the framework version you are targeting. You need 3.5 or greater. The VB.NET Compiler should import the System.Linq namespace for you. (Look on the References tab of the Project's properties).

Comment: OK, I am comparing dates.  When I use my line `a.Sort(Function(x, y) x.DelegationDate.CompareTo(y.DelegationDate))`, it doesn't sort at all.  It leaves it in the original order.

Comment: @JayImerman I think you should start a new question with more information about the classes and dates you are trying to sort, and more could around your example.

Comment: My list was defined as `Dim list = new List(Of Person)` and I had to use `list = list.OrderBy(Function(x) x.zIndex).ToList` to get the sorted list.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a custom comparison to sort the list:

```
nList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.zIndex.CompareTo(y.zIndex))
```

Comment: @DalexL: You import the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @DalexL: Note that you don't need Linq for the solution that I suggested.

Answer (score 6):

If not LINQ, then you can implement the IComparable(Of ClassName) to your class:

```
Public Class ClassName
  Implements IComparable(Of ClassName)

  'Your Class Stuff...

  Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As ClassName) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of ClassName).CompareTo
    If _ZIndex = other.ZIndex Then
      Return 0
    Else
      If _ZIndex < other.ZIndex Then
        Return -1
      Else
        Return 1
      End If
    End If
  End Function
End Sub
```

and then from your code:

```
nList.Sort()
```

Comment: You can shorten that entire `CompareTo` method to `Return _ZIndex.CompareTo(other.ZIndex)`