# How to get top 10 rankings in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a list of student rankings in VB .NET, wherein I have students and their grade averages. The problem is I need to solve is: I want to get the top 10 highest scoring students, but what if two or more have the same score? (For example if 2 students have the same average the list will become 11 since there is a tie and so on.) How can I keep the list limited to just the top 10?

I'm sorry I don't have any source code since I can't figure it out.

Thanks, SO.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Here,we learn/share our knowledge.Asking a question in the right format helps us to help you.Please read [ask] and take the [tour].You must show us some code/what you've tried..That's how we can help you

Comment: `I don't have any source code since I can't figure it out` Then your post is premature.  This is not a code writing factory or homework completion service,  Do some research, do lots of research and perhaps pay better attention in class.  So is for getting help with specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Start by watching [this tutorial on Lists in VB.NET](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6Z3yeaZlkU).

Once you have your list constructed, you'll want to **[sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478673/sorting-a-vb-net-list-by-a-class-value)** (by grade average, descending) and **[limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677398/2575069)** it (to 10 results). There should be multiple ways to accomplish this; now that you know the terms to search for, you should be able to find some helpful tutorials by Googling.

Answer (score 0):

So...you don't have any source code ??!!! So,why did you say :

> I have students which have their Grade Ave

Where do you have them ? Or you just want your application to have it ?

If you want your application to have the data of the students,then you have a several options regarding data management.

1 • [Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

2 • [Microsoft Acces](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040)

3 • [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)

4 • [PostGre](https://www.postgresql.org/download/)

5 • [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643888/insert-new-element-to-xml)

After you're done choosing the right database software,the next part is of viewing the data in your appliation.For that you can use :

1 • [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms),[Load data into DataGridView]9http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/how-to-load-data-from-database-into-datagridview-in-vb.net)

2 • [ListBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx),[A tutorial on ListBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gquKlyJR94Q),[A tutorial on populating a ListBox from Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7cCfCQ7E6Y)

Now,when you're done with displaying the data from the database in your application,you need to sort/filter the data(i mean the control you are using)
For this , you can take a look at :

1 • [Sorting datagridview](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_sort.htm),[A detailed tutorial on sorting the DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-sorting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control),[The DataGridView.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z(v=vs.110).aspx)

2 • [A basic tutorial on sorting the ListBox](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/SortListBox.htm) ,[The ListBox.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort(v=vs.110).aspx),[Another tutorial on ListView Sorting](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?505745-RESOLVED-2005-Sorting-a-Listbox-Descending)

Hope this helps!